# Compare object attributes with array of objects Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an object that I want to compare with an array of objects. If two specific attributes are equal I want to stop the loop. How can I do that, or how can I do this in some better Rails way?

```
@item #item to compare with


        @items.each do |item|
            if ( (item.att1 == @item.att1) && (item.att3 == @item.att3) ) 
                is_equal(item.id) 
            else
                #do something
            end
        end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) method of an Array:

```
matched_item = @items.find { | item | item.att1 == @item.att1 && item.att1 == @item.att1 }
is_equal(matched_item.id)
```